# unexpected at this time Jdeveloper12c

Tags: oracle12c, weblogic12c, jdeveloper

I install Jdeveloper 12 and i setup the server, when i start the server this appear in log 
"*** Using HTTP port 7102** 
 **Using SSL port 7107 ***
C:\Users\MYPC\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd
[Starting IntegratedWebLogicServer.]
[waiting for the server to complete its initialization...]
C:\Program was unexpected at this time.
Process exited.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer terminated.]"

What exactly this error, and how i can solve it?

Comment: Under Windows, installing WebLogic under a directory which contains spaces in its name is not supported... Uninstall an re-install WebLogic in anthoer folder.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand.

Comment: you may have installed JDev under C:\Program Files\... Install it in a folder whose name do not have a space in it. C:\jdev for instance

Comment: i installed it in C:\Oracle\Middelware  is that the problem ??

Comment: That' ok. Take a look at the file C:\Users\MYPC\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.2.1.2.42.170105.1224\DefaultDomain\bin\startWebLogic.cmd. It launches a program which is in C:\Program Files, maybe java.

Comment: yes it is launches java

Comment: can you post the statement plz ?

Comment: set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS%

Comment: Dear @EmmanuelCollin, how i can change this path SEVERE: only one default export specification allowed (C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\plugins\jdeveloper\libraries\JAX-WS_Client.library, line 4, column 78)
its appear when i start the jdeveloper, but its not correct path so i need to change it please!